# Can I pass Variables inside IN Clause when using pivot operator

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, pivot

Can I pass Variables inside IN Clause when using pivot. I mean how can I do it:

```
pivot(Sum(Column1) for [Column2] in ([@variable1] , [@variable2] , [@variable3]) ) as pvt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max) = '[Column1], [Column2]'

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
pivot (
Sum(Column1) for [Column2] in ('+@cols+')
) AS PVT'

EXEC(@sql)
```